# Is it possible to "hide" the tool bars, bookmarks and more else from de browsers?

Tags: javascript, html

Whit the following code, I can go to a new window, hidding several components from the browser...

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:visualControl('newpage.html'); return false;"> 

 SampleText!

</a>

function visualControl(str) {
    window.open(str, 'popupwindowalpha','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,menubar=no'); 
}
```

BUT I need to open a page whit all this set up, Is this possible,
OR maybe "turn ON/OFF" by a button in the same page..

**NOTE**, this is for a **internal use**, for an **intranet**, I do not want do block the user's freedom.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If it's internal, https://www.google.com/search?q=kiosk+mode

Comment: VERY nice info!!!  tks a lot !!!!